# django could not import settings

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I once wrote an django app, named `superlists`, and settings was in `superlists.settings`. It was for tutorial, and I was changing differnt settings, little realizing what I was doing.
And now when i starting new django project - it tells me it could not import `superlists.settings`

I reinstalled Pycharm, django, python (both versions 2.7 and 3.3), deleted all virtual envs, deleted everything that might be connected to it several times... IT IS STILL THERE! on a new, clean version of python, which even dont have django - there is `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` in `sys.path` pointing to `superlists.settings`. Each new project on a clean, with default settings, version of pycharm, tells me that it cannot import `superlists.settings`.

I delete `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` pointing to that settings from `sys.path` from cmd - exit then watch again - its there.

Where it takes it? I got no idea.
here is traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/django/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
management.execute_from_command_line()
File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
commands = get_commands()
File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 132, in __init__
% (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'superlists\settings.py' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): Import by filename is not supported.
```

Comment: what happens if you run `python manage.py runserver --settings=superlists.settings`? did you get the same error?

Comment: Have you checked if `site-packages` is getting erased when uninstalling Python? `Lib\site-packages` folder tend to survive from installation to installation.

Comment: I deleted only django from site-packages manually once. No use. I will try to delete a whole thing, thanks. `python manage.py runserver --settings=superlists.settings` starts server without problems, i didnt move that settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I created new environment system variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE. So evident, but it almost cost me sanity.

Comment: It seems that I'm having the same problem. Can you be more specific on how to solve it, please? Tks

Comment: If it is you issue, you should [delete environment system variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (if it is there). Otherwise django will always look for settings where this variable points to. I think its a bad practise to use this variable at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change the environment variable from

`DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=superlist.superlist.settings`

To `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=superlist.settings`

or use an `__init__.py` in superlist