# Gunicorn ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I am having an issue running Gunicorn for a django project. When I run:

```
Gunicorn superlists.wsgi:application
```

from the command line I get

```
ImportError: No module named 'superlists'
```

If I follow the Django documentation at:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

It says for the command “gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application”
It requires that your project be on the Python path; the simplest way to ensure that is to run this command from the same directory as your manage.py file.

So I took the recommendation of the python docs and ran this from the directory that has my manage.py… but I get the same thing..

I “do” have a python module name superlists in the directory that has my manage.py and it does have a wsgi file with and application attribute.

So here are my questions: I assume I am receiving this error because the module superlists is not in my python path. Is this correct?

If so then shouldn't my module be in the python path if I run it from the directory with my manage.py… as the Django docs recommend?

If not then is there something else I need to do to get the superlists into my python path?

BTW i am using a virtualenv and i have check that the virtualenv is using the correct python and gunicorn files...

Comment: Are you in the bash command line when you try running `gunicorn superlists.wsgi:application`? Is a directory named `superlists` in the same directory as your `manage.py` file where you are running this command? Does that `superlists` directory contain a `wsgi.py` file?

Comment: Yes to all of these.

Comment: See please here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20830299/django-could-not-import-settings

Comment: can you post your project structure here ?

Answer (score 1):

found it. I was trying start gunicorn with "superlists" but my application was actually superlist" with no "s"...... Thanks for the replys